# How to remove .JSP extension for all JSP page on a project

Tags: jsp

I create a project with JSP using  Eclipse EE. How to remove all .JSP extension? For example, localhost:8080/Project/**signin.jsp** to localhost:8080/Project/**signin**

Besides remove the JSP extension, can I access it with different name, like localhost:8080/Project/**login**

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use `servlet-mapping`

```
<servlet>  
     <servlet-name>Project</servlet-name>  
     <jsp-file>signin.jsp</jsp-file>  
</servlet>  
<servlet-mapping>  
     <servlet-name>Project</servlet-name>  
     <url-pattern>/signin</url-pattern>  
</servlet-mapping>
```

or you can use the [UrlRewriteFilter](http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/)

Comment: I have added servlet mapping like above code in WEB-INF/web.xml file. But when I access /signin, it gives me 404 not found error

Comment: no, this is working fine @ZZZ , make sure you have the correct absolute paths +1